# Rails/ActiveRecord Model.Find returns the wrong record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the wackiest.

When I visit:

```
/ingredients/14.json
```

I get

```
{ id: 13,
  name: "Tomato",
  category: "Vegetable",
  created_at: "2013-11-20T04:35:36.704Z",
  updated_at: "2013-11-20T05:59:34.444Z"
}
```

And in the logs:

```
Started GET "/ingredients/14.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-19 22:02:35 -0800
Processing by IngredientsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"14"}
  Ingredient Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE (14) LIMIT 1
#<Ingredient id: 13, name: "Tomato", category: "Vegetable", created_at: "2013-11-20 04:35:36", updated_at: "2013-11-20 05:59:34">
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

There are only two items in the database, #13 (tomato) and #14 (egg).

I'm using:

- Rails 4.0.0
- SQLite (it's a brand new app :)
- ActiveModel::Serializers (although I found the same result when I removed the gem and the serializers)
- Powder (but this continues *after* `powder restart`!)
- Batman.js (but this occurs when Batman requests JSON **and** when I visit the URL with my browser)
- Chrome (although it also happens in Safari *and* in Chrome Incognito)

I have no idea what this could be? Any guesses?!

### Update

It was just me being an idiot. Check out my bad controller action code:

```
  def show
    @resource = @class.find_by(params[:id])
    respond_with @resource
  end
```

of course, this should be:

```
  def show
    @resource = @class.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @resource
  end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Upgrading to Rails 4.0.1 didn't help :(

Comment: Happens to all of us at some time! Do I get an accept vote? ;)

Comment: you bet -- it's just making me wait 2 more minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your generate SQL is wrong. The query generated is:

```
SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE (14) LIMIT 1
```

whereas it should have been:

```
SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" WHERE id = 14 LIMIT 1
```

Since the condition in the first where clause always evaluates to true, it picks up 1 row randomly. Which row gets picked up depends on how your DBMS stores data internally.

To know why the generated query is wrong, we'll need to see the code in your Controller's action.